# Fabric: hide stdout for remote jobs, but only show a 'grep'ed line

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, fabric

I want to show stdout for my local program, which uses fabric to run two remote programs. I want to hide the stdout for the two remote programs. (I know there is a hide output option). However, I do want to show one of the print statements (can be grepped) from one of the two remote programs.

How can I do this?

The structure is as follows:

```
Process 1:

with settings ():
    run(cmd)

start Process 1


Process 2:

with settings ():
    run(cmd)

Start Process 2
```

I can probably do:

```
with hide('output'):
    run(cmd)
```

But that hides the output of the remote program completely.
I want to be able to show one particular stdout line from one of the remote programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the grepped output to a variable then print the shortened output

like this:

```
content = sudo('git status | sed -n 2p | grep -w "Your branch is up-to-date"')

print (content)
```

Hope it helps !!